# compressing information into a short code

Tags: php, encoding, compression

I need to group a number of parameters into a short, non-predictable, spellable code. Ex:

- serial: WJ-JHA5JK7E9RTAS
- date: 04/02/2013
- days: 30
- valid: true

Compressed code could look like this: **3xy9b0laiph3s**

My goal is to make the code as short as possible (without losing any information, of course). The algorithm must be easily implemented in other languages as well (so it can't have crazy specific dependencies). Any thoughts?

Comment: By non-predictable do you mean encrypted?

Comment: well, yes. but i can't afford the code to be too big, so i think formal encription would not fit...

Comment: To 'safely' shorten your data first you could use a cryptographic one-way hash function (MD5, SHA-1, &c.). (If your data is longer than the output of these functions in the first place, of course.) This will boil down your data to a specific length while minimizing the risk of collisions. - If used with a secret 'salt' the resulting data will be as unpredictable as it gets. -- Oh, of course you lose information this way, but to verify/look up the original data this will work fine.

Comment: Well, does the OP want to be able to recover his data from the code?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time this is handled by storing the data somewhere and creating an ID which is then compressed and used. The most common users of this system are short URL sites.

- Store data in DB and get row ID
- convert base-10 row ID to base 32 or 64 (base_convert in PHP)
- use the new ID which looks like '4F7c'
- When that ID is passed just unconvert it bask to base 10 and look up the data in the DB

Code:

```
$id = 23590;
print $id;
$hash = base_convert($id, 10, 32);
print $hash;
$id = base_convert($hash, 32, 10);
print $id;
```

Comment: I wish i could do that :( ~ sadly, the code has to contain the information itself.

Comment: @hugo_leonardo, I'm afraid then that you can't do what you want. No one has published an ASCII based compression algorithm that reduces the size of the input without using a shared library. You either have to compress it to binary with something like gzlib or base64 encode it which adds 33% to the size of the string.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary short strings there is not enough information to apply generalized predictive methods of compression.

You'll need to exploit the known features of your data.

Example:

- Serial numbers appear to be capital letters and numbers - 36 values per character - and 15 characters long. That's 36^15 possible values which will fit in 78 bits.
- Date can be converted into number of days since a fixed date. If all the dates are known to fall within 100 years of each other, this can be stored in 16 bits.
- If days is never more than years worth, this can be stored in 9 bits.
- Valid can be stored in 1 bit.

That's 104 bits, which can be Base64 encoded to 18 characters

Note that oftentimes serial numbers have a checksum character or two. If you know how the checksum is calculated, you can omit this character and recalculate it upon decoding. This could save you a Base64 digit here.

If you want to make the result less predictable, without worrying with heavy encryption, you can just deterministically shuffle your encoded string.

Comment: Note also that many serial number do not employ certain letters, such as "O" because they look too similar to numbers -- "0". Thus, there could be fewer than 36 values per character.

Comment: i guess that's the way to go :p ~ unfortunately i'll have to use base36 because the code is intended to be spelled over the phone (so it can't mix cases)

Comment: Spelled over a phone? Meaning voice recognition or entering on a touch tone keypad? The latter only gives you 10 digits + 2 if you use "*" and "#", but one of those will probably have to be your end-of-transmission terminator. A person entering "D" or "E" or "3" is indistinguishable over touchtone. The former seems like it would be easier just to speak the unencoded information.

Comment: not fancy like that. just spelled by the company internal staff and then manually entered by the client. it's an old proccess that i'm not allowed to change...

Comment: So typed on a telephone keypad then? If so, there is no hope of compressing the information. Indeed, you need to decompress the serial number so it can be expressed on a 12-key pad.

Answer (score 0):

UUencode or Base64, but in these codings case is matched. Eventually you could edit these codings for your purposes (only small letters). If you have exactly the same amount of data this would be the easiest solution. But not the minimal one.

Comment: but how to convert the data into a number (and revert it back) so i can change the base? the base64 encode function actually makes the information bigger (even with numbers, and i don't event know why).

Comment: You have only letters, digits, a date, number that is in some range and a bit. You can pack these information by converting letters with digits to smaller pieces (bits for every character, because every of them is in some range - letters A to Z in range 65-90, digits 48-57 and small letters 97-122) and then represent them by what you want. Change characters to 62 or 64 bit chunks, the rest of the information and you are done.